AIS messages: What are the percentages at the end of ShipName field?
I am becoming familiar with Automatic Identification System (AIS) in order to analyze the data.  I found that some MMSIs map to multiple ship names.  Often, the ship names differ only in the percentage data at the end of the ship name.  Examples from aisstream.io:
MMSI      ShipName
--------- -----------------
941500551 LISA BUOY 4 [42%]
941500551 LISA BUOY 4 [40%]
941500551 LISA BUOY 4 [41%]

109050897 NORSOL 5    [69%]
109050897 NORSOL 5    [70%]

What is the significance of these percentages?

MMSIs have an internal structure and identify much more than ships. E.g. DSC-EPIRBs are emergency radio beacons, that also have MMSIs and are able to send position infos using AIS (depending on model). Those MMSIs might be issued by manufacturers and you should be able to identify those, then look at their specs. So those % could be battery…

Curious.  There are so many different message types with different fields, yet some devices will embed batter information in the Ship Name.

If you found out that is it, please answer the question yourself, describing how you got there. This will help people having the same question. Thanks

Sorry, I might have been unclear.  I don't know that the percentages are battery information.  I was responding to you by commenting on that possibility.

I see. And I was just guessing :-D
